# Windows XP Delete File Option

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, recycle-bin

When I go to delete files in XP, it's deleting them directly.  I had my machine recently reimaged, and this feature changed (no longer says are you sure you want to do this).  Where does  the configuration of the prompt appear in windows XP?  I thought maybe folder options but I don't see anything resembling that there.

I want to turn on the prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the Recycle Bin, then Properties and check Display delete
confirmation dialog.

That will do!

Answer (score 0):

The right-click properties on Recycle will give you the delete confirmation option.

Note that you can have *also* the best of both worlds by holding down Shift when you delete something, which will delete the file immediately not putting it the recycle bin.  It's much faster to delete that way, at the expense of not being able to recover.